# Найти размеры внутреннего прямоугольника после изменения внешнего

Tags: алгоритм, геометрия

Задача по сути простая (или может мне так кажется), но что-то не могу придумать никакого алгоритма пока что. Вобщем, нужно найти новые размеры внутреннего прямоугольника содержащегося в другом размеры которого изменяются произвольно.

Известны размеры внешнего и внутреннего прямоугольника и величина изменения внешнего.
Никакой из прямоугольников не повёрнут - тоесть стороны всех прямоугольников всегда параллельны друг другу.

Для прояснения проиллюстрирую
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какие варианты решений ?

Comment: А почему размеры внутреннего прямоугольника не остались теми же?

Comment: @VladD это не важно, внутренний прямоугольник изменятся пропорционально внешнему

Comment: Если внутренний изменяется пропорционально внешнему, можно посчитать изменение внешнего ((W+a)/W, (H+b)/H). Далее умножить w1, h1 на полученные значения.

Comment: @VladD тоесть если ширина внешнего изменилась на какую то величину то ширина внутреннего тоже изменяется на какую то определённую величину, но на какую ? весь вопрос в этом (и тоже самое с высотой)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
w2=w1*(W+a)/W
```

Аналогично для высоты

P.S. Прошу прощения, ответ уже есть (не заметил решения в комментариях)

Comment: можно пояснения к этой формуле ?

Comment: Толкачёв Иван объяснил в своем комментарии